# How to merge two SonarQube instances

Tags: merge, sonarqube

Currently we are running two sonar instances in different locations, we are planning to merge these two instances to one. Is it possible to merge two SonarQube instances?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted! We have the same issue! :) Inorganic growth can easily cause this!

Answer (score 2):

This feature does not exist currently, and we don't expect to work on this in a near future.

The best advice we can give you is:

- Keep your biggest SQ instance
- For every project of your other instance, use the ["sonar.projectDate"](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) analysis parameter to rebuild your analysis history on the biggest instance. For example:

  - Check out code for version 1.0 and run an analysis with "-sonar.projectDate=2010-12-21"
  - Check out code for version 1.1 and run an analysis with "-sonar.projectDate=2011-08-13"
  - ...etc.